# Run tests for a BaseClass for all DerivedClass

Tags: python-3.x, nose, python-unittest

Given a little hierarchy of classes with some multi-inheritances and/or mixins (however you may call it).

I have a detailed test case (`unittest.TestCase`) for each individual base class and mixins.

How can I reuse those test cases for classes derived from the Base classes and mixins? I feel, that testing/asserting the derived class inherits from certain base classes isn't sufficient to ensure that it inherits the specific behavior of the base class(es).

I'd like to write something like:

```
class Base(object):
  # provides certain behavior

class Derived(Base, Mixin):
  # does some additional stuff compared to Base and Mixin

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
  # tests on Base's behavior

class DerivedTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.default = Derived()

  def test_has_behavior_of_base(self):
    # instead of
    self.assertIsInstance(self.default, Base)
    self.assertIsInstance(self.default, Mixin)
    # write
    self.assertPasses(BaseTest, Derived)
```

Is there a *pythonic* way of achieving this with Pythons `unittest` module and a maybe a little help of the `nose` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, since *Python* is a *duck-typed* language, it's best to minimize the checking for explicit types/classes (at least if you're going for a more *Pythonic* approach).

Since *duck-typing* relies primarily on behavior, and *nose* offers auto-detection of tests if you invoke it using a directory and name your test classes and methods accordingly (i.e. containing the word *test*, among others), I would recommend the following:

Define one test class for your *base* class, testing all of the behaviors of the base class. Factor out the common code into a non-test method, say `baseClassCore`, which calls the actual methods, gets the results, and then returns them. Then set up one test for each *derived* class which calls the `baseClassCore` code and asserts the expected results (if the assertion code is also common to all of them, that can also be factored out and then called from the test method).

Then, for the specific *derived* classes, create a test class for each of those which test just the behaviors unique to those classes.

You could, alternatively, call `baseClassCore` in a test for that specific type in the *derived* class test instead of the *base* class test -- it's a matter of preference.

Once these are all defined (and many of them will simply be wrappers around the core code so they get split out as separate tests in the *JUnit* results and are passed the specific types desired), running *nose* against the whole directory should detect and run them all. If you run with the *-v* flag, you'll get the method name as it runs, or, if it exists, the docstring underneath the method signature instead of just status letters.

Note that you don't need to use *unittest* explicitly. If you derive your test classes from `unittest.TestCase`, that's sufficient for *nose* to get that *JUnit*-compatible behavior.

As an aside, if you have any config that's needed (cutoff dates, servers to use, etc.) *nose-testconfig* is very convenient (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig). I usually use it with a *JSON* file, which is then fed into a `dict` named `config`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a filled out example that runs. Square is derived from Rectangle. If we derive TestSquare from TestRectangle, where TestRectangle is derived from unittest.TestCase, then all the test methods from TestRectangle will also be run from TestSquare.

```
import unittest


class Rectangle(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    def get_area(self):
        return self.get_width() * self.get_height()

    def get_width(self):
        return self._width

    def get_height(self):
        return self._height

    def set_width(self, width):
        self._width = width

    def set_height(self, height):
        self._height = height


class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, side):
        self._side = side

    def get_width(self):
        return self._side

    def set_width(self, width):
        self._side = width

    def get_height(self):
        return self._side

    def set_height(self, height):
        self._side = height


class TestRectangle(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.default = Rectangle(2, 3)

    def test_area(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.default.get_area(),
            self.default.get_width() * self.default.get_height())

    def test_set_get(self):
        self.default.set_width(4)
        self.default.set_height(5)
        self.assertEqual(self.default.get_width(), 4)
        self.assertEqual(self.default.get_height(), 5)

class TestSquare(TestRectangle):

    def setUp(self):
        self.default = Square(3)
```